# How to get the endpoint of a vector by quaternion?

Tags: vectors, 3d, quaternions

If I have the start point of a vector(not zero), and I also have the magnitude and the quaternion of the vector, how can I get the end point?

Comment: When you say "the quaternion", what exactly do you mean? Do you mean the quaternion representing the rotation that has been made from some standard starting direction?

Comment: I mean the rotation of the vector, which is represented by quaternion.

Comment: In standard terminology, a vector doesn't have a "rotation". The closest thing that comes to mind would be a "direction", and directions are usually represented by vectors, which doesn't help here. In order to represent a "direction" with a quaternion, two things come to mind: (1) the quaternion has unit norm, encodes a rotation, and there is an agreed upon standard starting direction as Arthur puts it, or (2) the quaternion is pure imaginary and is equivalent to a vector.